# What is the purpose of a movss instruction with [this] as destination?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, 64-bit, sse

I found this line in code generated by the MSVC compiler from Visual Studio 2008, while trying to figure out what seems to be a compiler bug:

```
movss dword ptr [this], xmm2
```

Although I do not think it is related to the bug I was looking for, I was like what the bleep? Storing a float value (completely unrelated to `this` btw) in `[this]`?

What exactly does that line do? Because I sure can't make sense of it! Or is the disassembly view playing tricks on me?

Comment: Is this really disassembly, or source code containing inline assembler?  I ask because `this` is a C++ keyword, with no meaning in assembler.  The `this` pointer is most often stored in `ecx`.  On the other hand, the x64 compiler doesn't support inline assembly.

Comment: It is what appears in the disassembly view of the MSVC debugger. [this] is the symbol (I have debug symbols) of the first input parameter to the function I am looking at.

Comment: But maybe the debugger displays this wrong. Anyway it is not inline assembly. The code is compiled for x64 which does not allow that.

Answer (score 4):

Providing some more assembly and/or source code would really help, but I see at least two possibilities:

1. `this` is not a this pointer, but just a random register pointing to some memory area. The disassembler named it such because it was used as a this pointer previously in the function or for some other reason.
2. `this` does point to a class instance, and the class has a floating-point field as a first member and no virtual methods.

Comment: Hmm I think you are right in the first case Igor... My true 'this' pointer points at 0x0000000031593FC0 while the disassembler [this] points at 0x00000000becccccd. Now to figure out what that represents...

Comment: @thehan why don't you post more code? is it some super-secret stuff?

Answer (score 3):

The xmm registers don't necessarily contain float values. They are 128-bit wide SIMD registers which basically means that one or more values can be stored inside the SIMD register; usual configurations are 8 16-bit ints, 4 32-ints, 4 floats, 2 doubles; etc.

However, the compiler is free to put whatever it likes in there and as long as the first element of 'this' is 32-bits you're good.

Comment: But as far as I see, this line would basically overwrite the vtable of 'this' since that is what occurs first at that address. And I know that xmm2 contains a float value that is not supposed to be written there... hmm.. EDIT: xmm2 previously loads a member variable that is a float and has not changed its value since.

Comment: If 'this' refers to the same 'this' as in C++, it's not going to overwrite the vtable; it's going to overwrite the first 4-bytes of the object it's writing to 'cause that's what movss does.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Intel manual on x86 instructions](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253666.pdf), MOVSS copies the lowest 32 bits of the XMM register. (Each XMM register is 128 bits long.)

While the instruction is called "move scalar single-precision floating-point value", you should really treat it as "move a 32-bit value". The instruction does not care if the data is actually a float or not; it just copies the bits without interpretation.

In your case, the instruction copies the lowest 32 bits of XMM2 to the memory location pointed by `this`. I think this is because your compiler is using XMM2 as a storage register (instead of using a general register like EAX).